# Entity Framework + SQL Server Compact + WPF/WinForms = Sluggish UI?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Entity Framework doesn't allow *sharing the same entity between multiple database contexts.* Therefore, I have to use only *one database context in a GUI application* (be it WPF or WinForms), because entities need to interact with each other.

SQL Server Compact doesn't allow *sharing the same database connection between multiple threads*. If I try creating a connection on one thread and running SQL query on another, my application is likely to crash.

Therefore, I have to *create EF database context on one thread and run all queries on that thread*. I've used GUI thread for that, because almost all queries are very fast. However, now I have a slow query and want to show an animated progress bar while it's being executed.

But I can't do that, because if I run a query on a different thread, my app crashes with AV. Furthermore, EF seems to complain if I run *multiple queries simultaneously*, even without SQL CE involved. Moving all queries to a different thread, covering all code with crazy amounts of async/await, callbacks, locks and other threading stuff sounds scary too, as I want to keep the code simple if it's possible.

**Question:** What is the correct way to work with EF database contexts and SQL Server Compact in a multi-threaded GUI application? Is there any way to offload individual queries to a different thread without making the whole application asynchronous, i.e. is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: But you could have one call that creates a dbcontext, opens a connection, executes a query, process the results and returns a list/dataset, can't you?

Comment: @rene It's GUI app. The requested entities are edited, connected entities are created/edited, there's autocompletion and other features which operate on entities. If I get an entity from one dbcontext, then put another entity from another dbcontext into its navigational property, EF will complain. These operations are separated in time, I don't know beforehand what entities the user will need.

Comment: In my experience using EF as a top-to-bottom ORM for anything but the simplest GUI is a path to madness. The need to have multiple entities in memory and connected to a context suggests you're doing business logic with EF, which is inviting just this kind of problem. Instead, consider using it strictly as a DAL to handle CRUD functions for a separate object model.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server CE supports multithreading. But its objects like SqlCeConnection or SqlCeTransaction are not thread-safe. Each thread should use a separate connection.
An Entity Framework DataContext instance is designed to last for one unit of work (bussiness transaction). [The recommendation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737) is a context per a form.

You can either redesign your application and store/transfer data using [DTOs](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html). Or you can use Attach/Detach features of Entity Framework ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896271%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676)). Or combine both.

Comment: One context per form works fine only while forms are simple. Let's suppose I have search functionality in the form which requires slow queries. If I move the query to another thread, I won't be able to use the entities I receive. If I detach and reattach them, I lose connected entities, lazy loading, change tracking; I'm also likely to run into cases when an entity with the same id is already attached. If I use DTOs and don't store contexts, the results are similar, but with more code and without id conflicts. I don't see any solution which doesn't sacrifice major parts of EF's functionality.